# Cannot save utf-8 encoded stuff in string

Tags: python, string, unicode, utf-8, python-2.7

I am querying the Twitter API and receive utf-8 encoded answers. Now I want to save these answers in a string with the `format()` function. This is what I have so far (and I have tried a lot of alternatives).

```
for user in userInfos:
    tName = user["name"] if user["name"] is not None else ""
    tLocation = user["location"] if user["location"] is not None else ""
    tProfileImageUrl = user["profile_image_url"] if user["profile_image_url"] is not None else ""
    tCreatedAt = user["created_at"] 
    tFavouritesCount = user["favourites_count"] 
    tUrl = user["url"] if user["url"] is not None else ""
    tId = user["id"] 
    tProtected = user["protected"] 
    tFollowerCount = user["followers_count"]
    tLanguage = user["lang"]
    tVerified = user["verified"]
    tGeoEnabled = user["geo_enabled"]
    tTimeZone = user["time_zone"] if user["time_zone"] is not None else ""
    tFriendsCount = user["friends_count"]
    tStatusesCount = user["statuses_count"]
    tScreenName = user["screen_name"]

    # Custom characteristics
    age = utl.get_age_in_years(birthdayDict[str(tId)])

    # Follower-friend-ratio
    if tFriendsCount > 0:
        foRatio = float(tFollowerCount)/float(tFriendsCount)
    else:
        foRatio = ""

    # Age of account in weeks
    numWeeks = utl.get_age_in_weeks(tCreatedAt)

    # Tweets per time
    tweetsPerWeek = float(tStatusesCount) / numWeeks
    tweetsPerDay = tweetsPerWeek / 7.0

    in_users.remove(str(tId))

    outputList = [str(tName),
                  str(tScreenName),
                  str(tProfileImageUrl),
                  str(tLocation),
                  str(tCreatedAt),
                  str(tUrl),
                  str(age),
                  str(tStatusesCount),
                  str(tFollowerCount),
                  str(tFriendsCount),
                  str(tFavouritesCount),
                  str(foRatio),
                  str(tLanguage),
                  str(tVerified),
                  str(tGeoEnabled),
                  str(tTimeZone),
                  str(tProtected),
                  str(numWeeks),
                  str(tweetsPerWeek),
                  str(tweetsPerDay)]

    pprint.pprint(outputList)
    fOut.write("{}{}{}{}{}{}{}\n".format(twitterUsers[str(tId)], outputDelimiter, outputDelimiter.join(outputList), outputDelimiter, utl.get_date(), outputDelimiter, utl.get_time()))
```

str(tName), str(tLocation) and the like give me errors when tName/tLocation contains stuff such as \xe4

```
ERROR:__main__:'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe4' in position 10: ordinal not in range(128)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../code/userinfo_extraction_old.py", line 167, in <module>
    outputList = [str(tName),
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe4' in position 10: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I have tried to understand how it works, but I cannot figure out what is wrong here. I have also tried to use unicode() instead of str()... no chance.

Comment: ...and you're running Python 2.something?

Comment: yeah, Python 2.7, forgot to mention that, sorry.

Comment: try str = str.decode('utf-8')

Comment: you mean I should put that above all my str calls, meaning to overwrite the default str function? or doing something like `str(tName.decode('utf-8'))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert `unicode` data to `str` you need to specify an encoding. Use `tName.encode('utf8')`, etc.

You may want to read up on Python and Unicode:

- The [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html)
- [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) by Ned Batchelder
- [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) by Joel Spolsky

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yeah I probably read one or two of those documents before, but since that topic is so overly boring, I always forget half of the stuff one week later... but thanks for the links anyway.